# howto read response commands from ftplibs?

Tags: python, ftp, ftplib

Have a code:

```
from ftplib import FTP
ftp = FTP('128.171.2.79')
ftp.login() # Anonymous user
```

Howto save the server responses into variable?

Example:

```
220-FileZilla Server 0.9.55 beta
220 Welcome to server!
530 Login or password incorrect!
214-The following commands are recognized:
   ABOR   ADAT   ALLO   APPE   AUTH   CDUP   CLNT   CWD 
   DELE   EPRT   EPSV   FEAT   HASH   HELP   LIST   MDTM
   MFMT   MKD    MLSD   MLST   MODE   NLST   N...
```

Into "buffer_out" variable.

Comment: I do not understand.

Comment: All, include the wellcome message. In this context, from wellcome message to login response.

Answer (score 1):

`buffer_out = ftp.getwelcome()`.

To get debugging log printed call 
`ftp.set_debuglevel(2)`.

To get every line sent by client override `putline()` or `putcmd()` (that is, create a class with FTP being its base class and implement these methods; call parent methods before or after).

To get every line returned by server override `getline()`, `getmultiline()` or `getresp()` and `voidresp()`; call parent methods before your code.

See the source code for ftplib.py, you may find many methods you'd want to override.

Comment: But is not all responses from server, from wellcome to login.Canot show commands with status 220, 530 and 214. Example: `$ ftp ip_addr ... 214-The following commands are recognized ...`

Comment: I extended the answer.